# Google Maps API V3. Delete default Marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I use the Google Maps API v3 Javascript.
I know add or delete a marker or an array with :

```
 MarkerLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
...
...
});
```

and

```
Marker.setMap(null);
```

But I want to remove a default marker on a GoogleMaps if it's possible.

Example :
When I go to Paris and I zoom in the city. I have marker metro/RER in my map. it is the means of transport in Paris. I want to remove this to use my marker.

It's possible to remove this or override this ?

Comment: Where does the marker come from? There are no (default-)markers in a map unless you add them.

Comment: by default, google add information on gardens, road, transit and I want to remove some information ! I read more the documentation of googleMaps API and I find my answer. I must apply a style to hide transit information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in the API documentation :

example :

```
var styles = [
{
    stylers: [
        { hue: "#00ffe6" },
        { saturation: -20 }
]
},{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
        { lightness: 100 },
        { visibility: "simplified" }
]
},{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
        { visibility: "on" }
]
},{
    featureType: "transit",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
        { visibility: "off" }
]
}
```

];